# Blazor Server Project with AAD Group policy

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, blazor-server-side

#### So, I can't use an `Application Role` but I can use an `AAD Security Group`. I am *authenticating* to my app just fine. But I am not sure how to *authorize* using an `AAD Security Group`.

Here's how I thought I would do it:

```
services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RegUser", policy => policy.RequireRole("MyAadSecGroup"));
});
```

Then I thought I could do this:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <AuthorizeView Policy="RegUser">
        <Authorized>
            <!-- Hello -->
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <!-- Goodbye -->
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

I *am* in the group, by the way. ;-) But, I get `<NotAuthorized>` every time.

Comment: Did you try `policy.RequireClaim` instead? For example: `RequireClaim("groups", "8e39f882-3453-4aeb-9efa-f6ac6ad8e2e0")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60883815/265706), I realized the syntax could be as easy as:

[image]

But after reading this [Microsoft Azure tutorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups) on the subject, I now see that getting access to a user's groups requires [Admin Consent](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups#register-the-web-app-webapp-groupclaims) and getting that in my organization is, well, impossible.

[image]

If anyone knows a different approach, I am VERY open to it. But, in the meantime, I can edit the **Enterprise App** for this **App Registration** and set it up to **require Users** and add my group to the Groups/Users list. This only supports ONE group, but it does not require Admin Consent from my enterprise administrator.