# How to get user's AAD memberships with @azure/msal-angular

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am using `@azure/msal-angular@0.1.4` (Microsoft Authentication Library for Angular) to enable AAD authentication in my Angular 8 application. So far, I only have 1 table in my database called emp (id, fname, lname, email) and I am using .net core as my back-end.

I did create 2 app registrations one for the my SPA and the other for my API. I already exposed the API and set the User Graph delegate permission in my AD to have user.Read and user.ReadAll.

My msaluser service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Msal from 'msal';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MsaluserService {

  private accessToken: any;
  public clientApplication: Msal.UserAgentApplication = null;
  public clientMembership: Msal.User = null;
  constructor() {
    this.clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
      environment.uiClienId,
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + environment.tenantId,
      this.authCallback,
      {
          storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
      });
  }

  public GetAccessToken(): Observable<any> {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('msal.idtoken') !== undefined && sessionStorage.getItem('msal.idtoken') != null) {
        this.accessToken = sessionStorage.getItem('msal.idtoken');
    }
    return this.accessToken;
  }

  public authCallback(errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) {
    if (token) {

    } else {
        console.log(error + ':' + errorDesc);
    }
  }

  public getCurrentUserFullName() {
    const user = this.clientApplication.getUser();
    alert(user.name);
  }

  public getCurrentUserEmail() {
    const user = this.clientApplication.getUser();
    alert(user.displayableId)
  }

  public getCurrentUserGroups() {
    // TO BE FETCHED
    // TO BE FETCHED
    // TO BE FETCHED
  }

  public logout() {
    this.clientApplication.logout();
  }
```

My app module looks like the following

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { MsalModule, MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MsaluserService } from '../_services/msaluser.service';

export const protectedResourceMap: any =
  [
    [environment.baseUrl, environment.scopeUri]
  ];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: environment.uiClienId,
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + environment.tenantId,
      protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap,
      redirectUri: environment.redirectUrl
    }),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpClient,
    MsaluserService,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MsalInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and my routes has a `canActivate: [MsalGuard]`

in my component.html I am calling these services and everything seem to be working perfectly. However, I am trying to get all user's AAD memberships along in the constructor of my msaluser service so I can call this function

```
public getCurrentUserGroups() {
        // TO BE FETCHED
      }
```

from any component I want when I inject the msaluser service in. Could you show me what code I should write in the `getCurrentUserGroups()` so I can get the logged in user's AAD memberships?

You should know that my dev environment array is like this

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl:'http://localhost:5000/',
  scopeUri: ['api://<API_APPLICATION_ID>/<NAME>'],
  tenantId: '<TENANT_ID>',
  uiClienId: '<SPA_APPLICATION_ID>',
  redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:4200'
};
```

**Update**

This is my method that I am trying to call but I am getting unauthorized request althought the accessToken is a valid JWT token

```
getCurrentUserGroups(): Observable<any[]> {
      this.httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.msalService.GetAccessToken()
          })

      };
      console.log(this.msalService.GetAccessToken());
      return this.http.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' + this.msalService.getCurrentUserId() + '/getMemberObjects', this.httpOptions)
          .pipe((response: any) => {
              return response;
          });
    }
```

Here is a screenshot to the decoded token, it does have the property `[hasgroups]` so I should be able to use my JWT token to query Microsoft Graph and get the security groups..

[image]

This token I am using to fetch employees info from my back-end repo (.net core) like the following:

```
getEmployees(): Observable<Emp[]> {
      this.httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.msalService.GetAccessToken()
          })

      };

      return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'emps/', this.httpOptions)
          .pipe((response: any) => {
              return response;
          });
    }
```

and it is authenticating properly and fetching the data.

Answer (score 0):

First, your access token is for calling your web API rather than Microsoft Graph.

And based on your code, the `this.accessToken` seems to be id token rather than access token.

So I'm afraid we cannot modify the `getCurrentUserGroups()` method directly to implement your requirement.

If you want to get the user's AAD Groups, the easiest way is to include Groups claim in your token as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes).

You just need to modify the "groupMembershipClaims" field in application manifest of the Azure AD app:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
```

Then the token will contain the Ids of the groups that the use belongs to like below:

```
{
  "groups": ["{group id}"]
}
```

In the `getCurrentUserGroups()` method, try to use something like `user.groups`.

But you can only get the group id here. So you may need to associate the group id and group name through the configuration file in advance.

In fact, there is another better way which combines Groups and Roles. You can [define some app roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) and assign the roles to the groups. Then the users in the group will have the "roles" claim.

See another similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58515744/get-azure-ad-user-group-by-azure-msal-angular-library-in-angular-8).

Comment: Hi, Allen.
I tried changing the groupMembershipClaims in my both app registration (SPA and API) to be like this "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup" but I am still not able to get the groups ids

Comment: My application was setup like this one in the link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/easily-enable-azure-ad-authentication-in-angular-and-web-api-core-app/

Comment: Also @Allen, how can I associate the group id and group name in the configuration file?

Comment: @Riad  Are you using implicit grant flows? And how many groups does a user have? If you are using implicit grant flows and a user has more than 6 groups, the `groups` claim will be replaced with `hasgroups` and you have to call Microsoft Graph in this case. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims.

Comment: @Riad "how can I associate the group id and group name in the configuration file", Write the group name and the corresponding group id in a configuration file in advance, and then read them.

Comment: The access token that I am getting is an actual JWT token {
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "kg2LYs2T0CTjIfj4rt6TIynen38"
}
with a valid signature.. isn't that enough to make the request 

this.http.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' + this.msalService.getCurrentUserId() + '/getMemberObjects', this.httpOptions)

Comment: I have updated my question to include getCurrentUserGroups()

Comment: @Riad Can you decode your access token in https://jwt.io and provide a screenshot of the decoded result?

Comment: I updated my question to include a screenshot of the decoded token

Comment: If I want to go the better route which is the using roles like you mentioned, will I get property [role] embedded in my JWT token rather than [has groups], or I need to make another separate call to MS Graph to get my role(s)?

Comment: is it maybe the version requested in the url or something I am missing in the url?

Comment: @Riad Looks like your access token is incorrect. I notice that `this.accessToken = sessionStorage.getItem('msal.idtoken')`. So it's id token rather than access token. Please check it.

Comment: aren't these considered claims? I am sending that JWT token to my backend to fetch data such as all employees info see the updated question

Comment: I am following this tutorial https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/easily-enable-azure-ad-authentication-in-angular-and-web-api-core-app/

Comment: @Riad This sample is using openId protocol and is calling own APIs. It doesn't require access token. If you want to call Microsoft Graph, access token is required. See this sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular. For how to get access token of Microsoft Graph, you may need to learn about: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user.

Comment: If I assigned security groups to roles like you suggested, will get the roles back in my JWT token, or I will also need to query MS Graph for that?

Comment: @Riad As I have mentioned, if your user has many groups (200+ with auth code flow or 6+ with implicit grant flow), the access token won't return the groups claim, it will only return `hasgroups`, in this case you still need to query MS Graph .

Comment: Allen, I got the groups idea, however, my question is about the roles specifically.. will my JWT token has the roles in the payload of the token?

Comment: @Riad Your token is id token rather than access token. You should acquire an access token for Microsoft Graph (not your own web API). See the links I shared above. Then the access token will has the roles.